# Decimal to Binary and consecutive 1's count

Tags: python-3.x

So, I was given this question where have to enter two numbers and find the binary representation of all the numbers between them and we have to check if there is consecutive 1's in the binary form, if present then skip otherwise print it.

I have tried this much I have created the required list of binary representation but now how to iterate over every number and check for that 1's possibility??

```
n = int(input())
m = int(input())
str=[]
for i in range(n+1,m):
    x = bin(i)
    str.append(x)
print(str)
```

Here is the output

```
3
7
['0b100', '0b101', '0b110']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So something like this:

```
def solve(a, b):
    result = []
    for x in range(a, b):
        binary_str = bin(x)
        if '11' not in binary_str:
            result.append(binary_str)
    return result
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
r = solve(a, b)
print(r) # ['0b100', '0b101']
```

Note that `bin` does not return binary but a binary representation (i.e. a string).

A slightly less efficient (because `bin()` is called twice) solution but shorter:

```
def solve(a, b):
    return [bin(x) for x in range(a, b) if '11' not in bin(x)]
print(*solve(int(input()), int(input()))) # 0b100 0b101
```